# 1kHz Tone Noise Detection and Analysis

Tags: python, numpy, audio, automation, pyaudio

I'm creating a python program which plays a 1kHz tone out of the line out headphone jack and listens for that tone on the microphone in jack (I have a AUX cable linking the two ports). Now I can "hear" and calculaate the frequecy of the tone using fourier transforms and I use a signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) equation to try calulate the quality of the signal, I also use RMS to see if there is any noise on the input when the tone is not played.

Now the frequecy calulation works perfectly, however the SNR value seems fairly arbritray and fluctuates massivly between tests! Is there a better way to detect noise on a mic in and when a 1kHz tone is being played? (reliably)

Results for SNR vary from about 0.4 to about 15.0! And I'm not confident to use this for detecting hardware faults just yet. I've only justv started playing with the RMS and this could be the way to go, but I am unsure.

The code I have used is below:

I pass in the audio buffer and an argument to choise wether or not to calulate SNR as this is pointless for when there is no tone being played.

def fourier_transform(stream_buffer, calculate_snr):

```
   snr = 0
   f_and_snr = []


   # Convert the stream buffer to a numpy array
   recorded_left_data = np.frombuffer(b''.join(stream_buffer), dtype=np.float32)


   # Calculate the RMS of the recorded signal
   rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(recorded_left_data)))


   # Perform Fourier transform on the recorded signal to get frequency
   len_recorded_data = len(recorded_left_data)
   f = np.fft.rfftfreq(len_recorded_data, d=1.0 /sampling_rate)
   f_signal = np.fft.rfft(recorded_left_data)
   spectrum = np.abs(f_signal)
   peak_frequency = f[np.argmax(spectrum)]


   if calculate_snr is True:
       # Calculate the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR)
       signal_power = np.sum(spectrum[np.logical_and(f > 990, f < 1010)])
       noise_power = np.sum(spectrum[np.logical_and(f > 0, f < 2000)]) - signal_power
       snr = signal_power / noise_power
  
   f_and_snr = [peak_frequency, snr, rms]


   return f_and_snr
```